# why does my 'if (isset) does not interact with mysql'

Tags: php, mysql, json, isset

why does my 'if if (isset($_POST['submit'])) not interact with mysql'
Please tell me, where do I go wrong, I've been over this a thousand times and checked the internet... It's a lot of code, but I think I have overseen something. I made the remarks for myself, so I would'nt forget something stupid as an ";". 
Thanks in advance

http://appsolute.vacau.com/cms

```
<html>
    <head>
    <title>Milan CMS</title>
    </head>

    <body>
    <?php
    mysql_connect("mysql15.000webhost.com", "a96443****tjiran", "ev****89") or die(mysql_error()); //opening database
    mysql_select_db("a9644326_app") or die(mysql_error());
    $result = mysql_query("select * from milan") or die(mysql_error()); //get msql database into $result
    $content = mysql_fetch_array ($result); // make $content represent current entry
    ?>

    <form action="<?php echo $PHP_SELF;?>" method="post" name="trainingen">
    <h3>Trainingen:</h3><p><textarea name="nametrainingen" rows="10" cols="60"><?php echo $content['value']; ?></textarea></p>
    <input type="submit" value="Verzenden"><input type="reset" value="Veld leeg maken">
    </form>

    <?php
    if (isset($_POST['submit'])) 
    { //test if submit button is clicked
        mysql_query("DELETE FROM milan WHERE tag='trainingen'") or die(mysql_error()); //delete old entry
        $input = $_POST['nametrainingen']; //set $input as current entry
        mysql_query("INSERT INTO milan (tag, value) VALUES ('trainingen', '$input')") or die(mysql_error()); //set tag, value as trainingen and $input(current entry)
        $result = mysql_query("select * from milan") or die(mysql_error()); //reset $result to new database
        $content = mysql_fetch_array ($result); //make $content represent new entry
        $myFile = "trainingen.json"; 
        $fh = fopen($myFile, 'w') or die("can't open file");
        fwrite($fh, json_encode($content));
        fclose($fh);
    }
    ?>
    <p>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Where is the problem description?

Comment: @PeeHaa: it is hiding in the title.

Comment: Answer has been posted, but something I would like to say; refrain from using mysql functions, use PDO or mysqli and learn to indent your code.

Comment: @Jocelyn I don't like hidden things. The title can mean anything.

Comment: Point taken, I watch it for the next time...edit: added the question

Comment: You should also take caution when catching form submission events by trying to detect the $_POST variable for the button.  IE will sometimes not post the submit button if the form is sent by pressing the return key etc.  It's best to insert a hidden field into your form and look for that instead.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`$_POST` is a super-global array that contains an associative array of all the form elements that were submitted with the form. You don't have an input with `name="submit"`, so your `isset()` fails.

Answer (score 3):

```
<form action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'];?>" method="post" name="trainingen">
```

not `$PHP_SELF`

Comment: Could you be so kind to tell me the difference?<br>edit: added it just to be sure...

Comment: Notice: Undefined variable: PHP_SELF

Comment: $PHP_SELF is one variable and has no any values that you assign on this before.

$_SERVER['PHP_SELF'] is has the value of that page where is your form.

Comment: You should also run PHP_SELF though htmlspecialchars() before outputting it to the user to prevent Cross Site Scripting (XSS) attacks.

Comment: Yes, that is my next step, thanx @PushparajJoshi for the answer, it is clear to me. And MarkR thank you also, because safety is my next step. As is the conversion to MySQLi, better learn it right...

Answer (score 2):

There is no tag whose "name" attribute is "submit" in your code.
Replace:

```
<input type="submit" value="Verzenden">
```

with:

```
<input name="submit" type="submit" value="Verzenden">
```

Comment: Wow, thanks a lot... That was just plain stupid, I knew it had to be something like that. It works and is updated... I have now weird behaviour with the updating of the textarea predefined content... Would you be so kind please to take another look online?

Comment: could you take a look at my previous remark? I have a hard time understanding the behaviour...

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="Verzenden">
```

But warning -your code is insecure. Search for SQL injections in google.

Comment: Thank you for the answer, I will do this in a later stadium... Ploughing through a lot of code at the moment.

Answer (score 1):

In your submit button `<input type="submit" value="Verzenden">`. You have missed `name="submit"`.

It should be

```
<input type="submit" value="Verzenden" name="submit">
```

Answer (score 0):

The submit button doesn't pass anything through to the form. To confirm that, you can try `var_dump($_POST)`. A substitute for that call would be

```
if (count($_POST))
```

However, you can still get notices and failed mysql queries so you should instead do

```
if (isset($_POST['nametrainingen']))
```